# Overview over current activities and results to represent GeoData semantically to allow formal reasoning

Tags: data, data-model, rdf, owl

I am currently interested in representing some geo-data in a semantic way via RDF/OWL to allow formal reasoning on a geometry level. However I am lacking a good overview  on the current standards to do so and on the benefits and limitations of each.

Can you recommend a good overview webpage or paper?

Answer (score 2):

This is rather old (1994) so predates RDF/OWL by a long way, but may be of theoretical interest. It was developed independently from, but around the same time as, Geographic Markup Language (GML), and is more of a conceptual discussion than a comprehensive catalog.

***Towards a geographic semantic database model***, by M Feuchtwanger (me). Here's the abstract:

> The management of geographic data is a great problem in  contemporary
>   cartography.  To date, little theory has been  developed to assist
>   such a task.  This thesis proposes a  geographic semantic database
>   model: a concept for the  design, construction, and use of geographic
>   databases.  The  work involved the synthesis of both general semantic 
>   database concepts and specific geographic information  concepts.
>
> A logical database model incorporates notions of the  structural and
>   behavioral aspects of stored information.  Structurally, a database
>   contains entities, relations, and  attributes.  Behaviorally, a
>   database has queries and  transactions.  Database models are evolving
>   from syntactic  to semantic forms, representing greater ability to
>   directly  and easily model reality.
>
> Any things of interest in geographic data processing can be  called
>   phenomena.  A phenomenon exhibits three primary  characteristics:
>   topical, spatial, and temporal.  That is,  it has some identification
>   and position, and exists at some  time.  Information on phenomena thus
>   exists within three  characterization domains.  It also exists within
>   three  abstraction domains: generalization, realization, and 
>   construction.  That is, geographic data have some accuracy  and
>   resolution, some form between reality and concept, and a  level of
>   meaning or applicability.  The characterization and  abstraction
>   domains are the particularly geographic ways for  logically
>   partitioning a collection of data.
>
> The proposed geographic database model contains entities,  such as
>   features, profiles, layers, and composites, which  represent
>   geographic phenomena.  The entities are  characterized by topical,
>   spatial, temporal, and scale  attributes, and by semantic, topologic,
>   and abstraction  relations to other entities.  They can be retrieved, 
>   displayed, or updated by database manipulations comprising  selections
>   and actions.  The entities also exist at  different levels of
>   abstraction: at different scales,  appropriate for different levels of
>   investigation; in  analytic or graphic form, depending on whether they
>   are to  be used for machine or visual processing; and as applied, 
>   basic, or primal constructs, appropriate for different  levels of use.
>
> Combining concepts from database management and analytical 
>   cartography into a geographic database model not only  facilitates the
>   analysis and design of geographic databases  but also is a step
>   towards a general theory of geographic  information management and
>   analysis.

It's available as a [PDF scan](http://summit.sfu.ca/system/files/iritems1/5579/b15196896.pdf) or [PostScript files](ftp://fraser.sfu.ca/pub/papers/feuchtwanger).